# Flask-Folium add to GeoJson data UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, flask, unicode, folium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnXqS.png) UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 100657: character maps to

I'm getting this error while adding to geojson data to my folium map

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
import folium
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

    
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
@app.route("/map")
def map():
    d = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    m = folium.Map(location=[39.92121147768605,32.81907498836517], zoom_start=2, tiles="Stamen Terrain")
    
    TurkiyeBorder = {
        "color " : "Black",
        "weight" : 0.2,
        "fillColor" : "Blue"        
    }
    
    Ankara_data = d + "/Ankara/Ankara.geojson"
    folium.GeoJson(Ankara_data , name = "Ankara", style_function=lambda x:TurkiyeBorder).add.to(m)
    folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
    
    m.save("map.html")
    return m._repr_html_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: That error means you tried to open a non-Unicode file. Without the full error it's hard to guess which line threw. The only line where the code seems to be loading a file is `folium.GeoJson(Ankara_data`. Perhaps the file was saved in the local codepage instead of UTF8?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hello Sir. I used Notepad to make the GeoJson file Unicode UTF-8. Actually, ı forgot to show full error. I'm editing my comment

Comment: Please [*do not* use images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. Then you know *at first sight* that the `charmap` refers to (and means) `cp1254` (not `utf8`)…